# Can 'though' introduce a clause?

Tags: word-usage

I'm a newcomer. Nice to see you. Is the following sentence right?

"There was little money left, we felt happy though." I'm not clear whether,"though", as an adverb, can introduce a clause. In other words:  "There was little money left, though we felt happy " can be replaced by "There was little money left, we felt happy though" ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don’t know what you mean by saying that *though* “is” an adverb. That isn’t right. A word outside of context is nothing, because it’s its function in a particular sentence, clause, or phrase that determines its part of speech — its role, if you would.

Comment: .....Lawlerian.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use *though* at the end of a sentence in this way, but this use is now colloquial.

When *though* introduces a clause, as in ‘There was little money left, though we felt happy’, it is a conjunction. ‘There was little money left, we felt happy though’, on the other hand, consists of two unconnected clauses, so you really need to show that by turning them into tw0 sentences: ‘There was little money left. We felt happy though.’

Answer (score 1):

The sentence isn't quite right. *Though* means "in spite of the fact that," so if you want to express the two thoughts in a single sentence, move "though" to the start of the other clause: "Though there was little money left, we felt happy."

Comment: Sorry and +1, Rebecca – missed this.

Answer (score 0):

As a conjunction, *though* has directionality ('in spite of the fact that'):

> [A] "There was little money left, though we felt happy."

doesn't mean the same as the more predictable

> [B] "There was little money left; we felt happy(,) though." [though = 'in spite of this' here]

A rewrite of the second sentence is:

> [B'] "Though there was little money left, we felt happy."